# Can I use Bash IF ELSE Statement Based on the day of the week

Tags: bash, date, if-statement

I am working on a script and I have 4 seperate Curl commands that I need to run dependent on the week of the month

ie if week 1 run curl 1
   if week 2 run curl 2

etc

there is only 4 and they only need to be run in the first 4 weeks of the month, week 5 doesnt matter.

any ideas?

Comment: What is your week definition? Is it the 1st 7 days form a week, or a week starts from the first sunday or monday?

Comment: I can be flexible. the first 7 days is good actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date` to get the day of the month then process against that.

```
day=$(date +%-d)
if [[ $day -le 7 ]]
then
   action1
elif [[ $day -le 14 ]]
then
   action2
elif [[ $day -le 21 ]] 
then
   action3
elif [[ $day -le 28 ]]
then
   action4
fi
```

Comment: I get an error when running this. line 4: [[: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
this is returned for all the date lines

Comment: numbers with padding zero are interpreted as octal

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions, here is a more esoteric one:

Create a function for each week's actions, week1..week5, plus one for an invalid week called weeki.

```
actions=(weeki week1 week2 week3 week4 week5)    # an array of function names
day=$(date +%-d)                                  # get the day of the month
index=$(( (day/7) + 1 ))                         # get the week number

eval ${actions[$index]}                          # execute the function
```

Comment: It works even without array, just change last line with `eval week${index}`

Answer (score 0):

`week1` ... `week5` are functions with different actions for different weeks.

Get day number from `date`, without padding zero (padding zero is interpreted as octal). `date +%-d` gives you the day of the month without padding zero.

```
day=$(date +%-d)
let "week=(day-1)/7+1"
case $week in
1) week1;;
2) week2;;
3) week3;;
4) week4;;
5) week5;;
esac
```

You can also use if ... elif

```
if [[ $week -eq 1 ]]
then
   week1
elif [[ $week -eq 2 ]]
then
   week2
elif [[ $week -eq 3 ]]
then
   week3
elif [[ $week -eq 4 ]]
then
   week4
elif [[ $week -eq 5 ]]
then
   week5
fi
```

Comment: `"week=(i-1)/7+1"` did you mean `"week=(day-1)/7+1"`?

Comment: Interestly, I wrote my solution at first with +%d, i.e. with a leading zero on the day.  Worked fine in Korn shell, but fell over as you predicted in Bash.